# Line out of guitar amp when connected to soundcraft notepad 8FX does not give sound to the mixer. Is the Line out busted?

Tags: audio-recording, mixer, amplifier, guitar, line-level

My guitar line out refuses to produce sound through the mixer.

I am beginner guitar player and for my first gig I went to the church to play for a communion, I was carrying my guitar (Juarez), a guitar amplifier (Palco 104), a DI box (Behringer DI100) and a soundcraft notepad 8FX mixer.  To connect to the churches PA, I had to connect the mixer output (XLR) to the PA but when playing the guitar, feeble or no sound came through the mixer.

Guitar Line out (1/4inch TS) --> (1/4 inch TS) DI box input (XLR)--> (1/4 inch TRS) Mixer Mic in --> PA system

I have tried to :

1. Connect the guitar directly to the mixer -- Feeble sound
2. Connect the guitar amp line out to the mixer -- No sound
3. Connect the guitar amp Line out to the DI box to mixer -- No sound
4. Connect the guitar to DI box to mixer ---  Low quality sound

As it turned out, I finally mic the guitar and it was no good, the mic picked up stray noises.
Would buying a cabinet emulator DI box help, the kind of Behringer Ultra-G GI 100, which has
a cabinet emulator help in getting the Line out of the guitar amp to produce sound on the mixer ?

Could somebody help me out ?

I really need to figure this one out, its frustrating.

Comment: Does the main PA not already have a mixing board? The 1/4 inputs on channels 1&2 are line inputs not mic inputs.

Comment: I use the Soundcraft Notepad 8fx mixer for recording to the computer.
Well, yes they are line inputs but labeled as Mic, so I use the channel 1 for the guitar input and channel 2 for mic. My main problem is that the line out on the guitar amp refuses to produce sound on the mixer.  I can't wrap my head around this one.

Comment: it could be one of a number of operator errors that we can’t help you with unless we were there and if not then you might have a broken piece of equipment.

Comment: Agreed, I will wait for the Behringer GI 100, with speaker emulation that arrives saturday and then update you.

Comment: @Timinycricket I tried to hook up the guitar AMP again and it worked.  YES It worked.  What is different is that I had the DI's battery fully charged now.  The other different thing was the monitor speakers were attached.  I can safely say :
1.  The DI boxes battery needs to be fully charged.

The question is resolved